# scrapy xpath return empty

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the list of events of olympic using Scrapy. I am pretty sure my XPath is correct. But it always return an empty list at the end. Any suggestion would be welcomed. Thanks

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Selector
from eventSpider.items import EventspiderItem

class EventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'eventsSpider'

def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = [
        'https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games'
    ]
    
    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_items)
        
def parse_items(self, response):
    eventsUrls = response.xpath("//div[@id='olympic-all-games']/div[1]/a/@href").extract()
    print("event url is: {}".format(eventsUrls))
    return eventsUrls
```

expected output:
the link to the individual event (link to Tokyo 2020, Rio 2016)

Edit:
As you can see in thee image, div[@id='olympic-all-games] is there. It helps limit the number of links we receive back as using //*[@data-cy="next-link"] would return may different type of links. But somehow scrapy doesn't recognize div[@id='olympic-all-games]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Your xpath doesn't return anything for me when I open it in the scrapy shell

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added it. expected output:
the link to the individual event (link to Tokyo 2020, Rio 2016)

Comment: when I test `//div[@id='olympic-all-games']` then already gives `None`. And when check page then it doesn't have `olympic-all-games`.

Comment: I get elements using `//*[@data-cy="next-link"]`

Comment: I have added to show the screenshot where I see olympic-all-games. //*[@data-cy="next-link"] would return all types of links while I am aiming to only get the links that are in the div of "relative past game"

Comment: now I see problem. These elements are added by `JavaScript` but `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need to use module `scrapy-selenium` to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

Comment: I see. I will try to find out how to use scrapy-selenium. Thanks. @furas can you please tell me how did you find out it was generated using JavaScript? so that I would know better in the future

Comment: I always frist turn off JavaScript in web browser and reload page to see what I can get with `scrapy` or `requests` or `urllib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with json and scrapy:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Selector
from eventSpider.items import EventspiderItem
import json


class EventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'eventsSpider'

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            'https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games'
        ]

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        data = response.xpath('//script[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()').get()
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        eventsUrls = []
        for game in json_data['props']['pageProps']['olympicGamesNoYog']:   # all the games from 2020 to 1896
            eventsUrls.append(game['meta']['url'])

        print(f"event url is: {eventsUrls}")
        return {'eventsUrls': eventsUrls[:10]}  # return the last ten games urls
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are incorrect. Try the below code. Note that I have simplified your code by removing unused imports and unneeded functions (at least for the snippet you have shared).

```py
import scrapy

class EventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'eventsSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games']

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath("//*[@data-cy='next-link']"):
            yield {
                'name': item.xpath("./text()").get(),
                'link': item.xpath("./@href").get()
            }
```

If I save the above code in a file named `olympics.py` and run the spider with `scrapy runspider olympics.py` I get below output.

```sh
2021-12-15 05:18:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games>
{'name': 'Paris 2024', 'link': '/en/olympic-games/paris-2024'}
2021-12-15 05:18:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games>
{'name': 'Milano Cortina 2026', 'link': '/en/olympic-games/milano-cortina-2026'}
2021-12-15 05:18:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games>
{'name': 'LA 2028', 'link': '/en/olympic-games/los-angeles-2028'}
2021-12-15 05:18:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://olympics.com/en/olympic-games>
{'name': 'Brisbane 2032', 'link': '/en/olympic-games/brisbane-2032'}
```